# Distributed Tensorflow: Workers Hangs

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed, worker

I am trying to implement a process-group idea of training network, by which we have several groups, each group contains a parameter server and some workers.

(worker1, worker2) -> ps1 ,

(worker3, worker4) -> ps2 ,

(ps1, ps2) -> central_ps

I want to use synchronized update within workers, which I tried to implement with tf.SyncReplicaOptimizer(), and I assigned worker1 as the chief worker.

However, only the chief group is training. The another group just hangs and prints

```
tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master_session.cc:998] Start master 
session 9443e0ca52a79c3a with config: device_filters: "/job:ps" 
device_filters: "/job:worker/task:0" device_filters: 
"/job:worker/task:1" allow_soft_placement: true
```

EDITED:
I guess it is a initializing problem. If I assign is_chief = True for one worker in each group (2 chiefs, in this case), then they run for a short amount of time. However, they hang quickly after both chiefs are fully on.

EDITED: The problem where it hangs is at session_manager.py(512)_ready()

```
-> if (ready_value is None or ready_value.dtype == np.int32 or
(Pdb) print(ready_value)
[b'ps_0/hid_w' b'ps_0/hid_b' b'ps_0/sm_w' b'ps_0/sm_b' 
b'copy_ps_0/hid_w'
b'copy_ps_0/hid_b' b'copy_ps_0/sm_w' b'copy_ps_0/sm_b']
```

It seems that all the variables on the non-chief groups are not initialized. I am trying to find a way to initialize them.

EDITED 3:
I update those variables by defining them globally on each device. That is, each worker runs (with device0), (with device1)
Now the variables that are not initialized becomes

```
[b'ps_0/hid_w/Adagrad' b'ps_0/hid_b/Adagrad' b'ps_0/sm_w/Adagrad'
 b'ps_0/sm_b/Adagrad' b'copy_ps_0/hid_w/Adagrad' 
 b'copy_ps_0/hid_b/Adagrad'
 b'copy_ps_0/sm_w/Adagrad' b'copy_ps_0/sm_b/Adagrad']
```

Trying to figure out what is happening.

EDIT 4:
After I move the graph definition totally out, now the codes can 
run
    sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target, config=sess_config)

However, it hangs at

```
_, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step], feed_dict=train_feed)
```

Where it is at

```
-> client/session.py(1306)_run_fn()
tf_session.TF_SessionRun_wrapper(
          session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
          run_metadata, status)
```

The code is linked at https://github.com/heyucongtom/PGRD/blob/master/syncreplica.py

Many thanks!

Comment: I solved the problem by separating defining graphs for each parameter server. That is, for workers on each ps, you define a separate graph. If we let every worker sees every parameter, then it will complain that some of the vars are not initialized.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your comment "define a separate graph"? I'm in a similar situation and I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Comment: This turns out to be a Tensorflow protocol problem. If you create 2 worker-server groups and hope that they works together, you need to initialize them separately. Please take a look at one of my post: heyucongtom.github.io